# child pane in settings.bundle xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, settings.bundle

The type option for child pane seems to have disappeared in XCode 6 and beyond. How exactly do I edit the type of root.plist in settings.bundle and give it the type Child pane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option for adding a child pane still exists for me, at least in Xcode 7 (which is what you should be using).

[I followed this tutorial just now](https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/ios-how-to-create-an-ios-settings-entry-for-your-app-using-settings-bundle/) and here's "child pane" in the popup list of types:

[image: Child Pane Popup]

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed. The secret is to set the value of the Type subitem to Child Pane. I also had problems unless Type was the first subitem inside the item that you want to become a Child Pane. Anyway, thanks.